# C++ - Shared pointer as a way to give state to a structure

Tags: c++, software-design

I have a question related to software design in C++. I'm writing a `gl_context` class that can create and manage opengl textures. Once the user creates a texture, the context returns a `gl_texture` structure, that can be later used by the user to operate on the texture. A copy of this structure is also stored inside an array in the context class. The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```cpp
class gl_context 
{
private:
    // stores all gl_texture created by gen_texture
    std::vector<gl_texture> textures_;

public:
    ...
    
    // generates a texture, stores it inside textures_ and gives a copy to the user
    gl_texture gen_texture();

    // sets the data for the texture identified by the given gl_texture object
    void set_data(gl_texture tex, int width, int height, unsigned char* data);
}
```

At the moment, `gl_texture` objects are stateless and immutable: once created, they can only be copied around but the information they carry does not change.

I would like to add a state to `gl_texture` in order to achieve the following behavior: once the user invokes `set_data`, the state of the `gl_texture` will change and it will also contain a valid width and height.

I can only think of one solution: passing around `std::shared_ptr<gl_texture>` instead of `gl_texture`. This way, there will only be one instance of `gl_texture` for each generated texture, and changes to the state will be visible to every user that holds a pointer.

Is this a good solution? Is there another way to design the `gl_context` class and solve this problem?

Comment: The title is not very explicative, I'm open to any suggestions

Comment: Could you tell why you need the `gl_context` class in the first place ? and also why split the `gen_texture` and `set_data` ? It could be simpler to always construct textures with complete informations, a la [glTexStorage2D](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml)

Comment: `struct context { int width; int height; gl_texture texture; };` and then `std::vector<context> textures_;`

Comment: @Eljay The OpenGL context is the object that OWNs all textures, shaders, VBOs, etc. A context is not a texture! You may have one, or multiple contexts in an APP. Some may be shared between multiple windows, or you may have a unique context per window, or you may have one shared between multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

## !!!! STOP !!!!

Take a big step back, and look at your design!

### Firstly: How is your gl_texture object defined?

If it in any way resembles the following, you'll need to go back and start over on your design!

```cpp
struct gl_texture {
   Gluint tex;
   gl_texture() { glCreateTextures(1, &tex); }
   ~gl_texture() { glDeleteTextures(1, &tex); }
};
```

This would cause a significant problem if you were to do:

```cpp
void do_thing(gl_context* myContext)
{
  // cool, generate a new texture object
  gl_texture tex = myContext->gen_texture();

  // now set the data or something
  myContext->set_data( /*snip*/ );

  // and now here, tex will fall out of scope, 
  // and the texture data will be deleted from the GPU. 
}
```

### Secondly: Maybe just use OpenGL instead?

> I would like to add a state to gl_texture in order to achieve the
> following behavior: once the user invokes set_data, the state of
> the gl_texture will change and it will also contain a valid width > and height.

Why are you trying to re-implement the OpenGL API? What improvements will your API bring that OpenGL doesn't already provide? For example, the following object is entirely immutable, however it will always track and return the correct width/height *(no matter when/where you modify the underlying texture object)*. What improvements will *your* re-implementation bring to the table?

```cpp
struct gl_texture {

   const Gluint tex; ///< ALWAYS immutable!

   int width() const { 
      int param = 0;
      glGetTextureLevelParameteriv(tex, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &param);
      return param;
   }
   int height() const { 
      int param = 0;
      glGetTextureLevelParameteriv(tex, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &param);
      return param;
   }

   // and for extra validation... 
   bool is_valid() const {
       return glIsTexture(tex) == GL_TRUE;
   }

};
```

Maintaining your own copies of the data that OpenGL is already managing is just re-inventing the wheel imho.

Answer (score 0):

Does the lifetime of a `gl_texture` really need to exceed that of the `gl_context` which created it?  If not, you do not need shared ownership semantics.  You can return a simple `gl_texture*` from `gen_texture()`, with a comment that the pointer is valid until the `gl_context` is destroyed.

If you do this, be careful of the `std::vector`.  If it needs to expand its capacity, the `gl_texture` pointers you've given out will be invalidated.  So either `reserve()` all the capacity you could possibly need at the start, or if that's not possible, use `std::deque` instead.

Comment: Returning a raw pointer can also become tricky if the `gl_context` provides a way to delete textures.

Comment: @rotoglup Returning raw pointers here would cause far fewer problems than returning a value!